# A monic quadratic trinomial $P(x)$ is such that $P(P(P(x)))=0$ and $P(x)$ have a common root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

A monic quadratic trinomial $P(x)$ is such that $P(P(P(x)))=0$ and $P(x)$ have a common root, then
$(A) P(0)\cdot P(1)>0$ 
$(B) P(0)\cdot P(1)<0$ 
$(C) P(0)\cdot P(1)=0$

Let $P(x)=x^2+bx+c$. I don't know how to do it further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(x)=x^2+bx+c\implies P(0)=c.$$
Let the common root be $\alpha$. We have,
$$P(\alpha)=0,\; P(P(P(\alpha))=0  \implies P(P(0))=0\implies P(c)=0.$$
Since $c$ is a root of $P(x)$ and the [product of the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) is $c$, the second root of $P(x)$ is $1$.
$$\therefore\; P(0)P(1)=0$$